# Appending to Vector

Tags: julia

I'm having trouble appending to an empty vector in Julia.

```
v = Int64[]
append!(v,1)
append(v,1)
```

The append! gives the error

```
ERROR: `Variable` has no method matching Variable(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

And append gives the error

```
ERROR: append not defined
```

This is probably a basic mistake on my part, but I can't figure out why neither command is working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're appending a scalar value, you want `push!`. If you're adding a list of elements, then you want `append!`. There's a good reason for the distinction, as you will probably realize if you consider what should happen if you want to build an array-of-arrays.

Typing `?append!` at the REPL will show you help on the function, including a demo on how to use it. (In julia 0.4, the help has been improved and refers you to the `push!` function as well, but that doesn't seem to have been implemented in the current release.)